# How to check if a bit in a bitset is zero or one?

Tags: java, indexing, bit, bitset

I have a bitset and I want to check whether a bit at a specific index is zero or one.

Comment: I got it I was confused while reading javadocs..Please close it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `.get()`:

```
return theSet.get(index);
```

It returns `true` if the bit is set and `false` otherwise.

[Javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: +1 Technically, you don't need to know whether a 0 or 1 is used or something else. BitSet will tell you if the "bit" is *set or clear*. For example if you ask for a bit, beyond the size of the BitSet, e.g. `new BitSet(32).get(64)` will return false even though there is no 0 or 1 as such.